# Find the last occurrence of a value in a row excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row with a date, and pass or fail values.

Refer to the following:

- Cell A1 has date 01/01/2020
- Cell B1 has either P or F for pass and fail
- Cell C1 has date 02/01/2020,
- Cell D1 P or F
- So on and so forth

I want to have a cell at the end that will identify the last occurrence of F and provide the date from the cell next to it in just that row.

Comment: No. There could be a F on the first occurrence, and numerous passes after.

Comment: But you want the latest date that has an F? Basically, are your dates in order left to right?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the following formula with CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER...

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B1:Z1="F"),A1:Y1)
```

Adjust the two ranges to suit your circumstance.